# code not executing. If i use color index = 3 or 2, it works , but not when i use RGB

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Clearall()

 Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        Dim Clrallblue As Range
    Set Clrallblue = Range("C14:I19")

    For Each Cell In Clrallblue.Cells
        With Cell
            .ClearContents
            .Borders.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
            .Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(153, 204, 255)

        End With
    Next Cell


End Sub
```

Comment: Color *index* refers to the *index* of a color in some palette, not to a RGB color.

Comment: Instead of calling each time `RGB` function, store its return value in `Long` variable: `Dim lngColor&: lngColor = RGB(153, 204, 255): /* your code */ .Interior.Color = lngColor`

Answer (score 3):

`.ColorIndex` requires an integer value. Use `.Color` instead if you want to use RGB.

Answer (score 1):

ColorIndex does not accept RGB please look here for the full color index tables:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/colorindex-property